# Query tuning required for expensive query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design, query-optimization

Can someone help me to optimize the code? I have other way to optimize it by using compute column but we can not change the schema on prod as we are not sure how many API's are used to push data into this table. This table has millions of rows and adding a non-clustered index is not helping due to the query cost and it's going for a scan.

```
create table testcts(
name varchar(100)
)
go
insert into testcts(
name
)
select 'VK.cts.com'
union
select 'GK.ms.com'

go

DECLARE @list varchar(100) = 'VK,GK'

select * from testcts where replace(replace(name,'.cts.com',''),'.ms.com','') in (select value from string_split(@list,','))

drop table testcts
```

Comment: The query isn't SARGable, so it can't be optimised unless you make it SARGable first. That means removing the `REPLACE` clauses around `name` to start with.

Comment: How many values are in `@list` on average? Consider first splitting this into a temp table and use it with *exists*

Comment: Aside: What happens to `'diseases.ms.comedy.edu'` when you do the `'replace'`? Is that what you want? Or `'cadillac.cts.commercialfleets.xxx'`?

Comment: column contains 3 type of values  like 'a.cts.com', 'a:cts.com' and 'a'. I implemented the same on cx env and now we have only 13 logical reads instead 147000 reads.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility might be to strip off the `.cts.com` and `.ms.com` subdomain/domain endings *before* you insert or store the name data in your table.  Then, use the following query instead:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM testcts
WHERE name IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@list, ','));
```

Now SQL Server should be able to use an index on the `name` column.

Answer (score 1):

*If* your values are always suffixed by `cts.com` or `ms.com` you could add that to the search pattern:

```sql
SELECT {YourColumns} --Don't use *
FROM dbo.testcts t
     JOIN (SELECT CONCAT(SS.[value], V.Suffix) AS [value]
           FROM STRING_SPLIT(@list, ',') SS
                CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('.cts.com'),
                                    ('.ms.com')) V (Suffix) ) L ON t.[name] = L.[value];
```

Comment: I discussed with cx to know exactly how many types of values are present and based on that I implemented the same.